# MAMP 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, windows, mamp

I've got MAMP Pro installed on my windows 11.

When i run `composer update` or `php -v` in my integrated terminal on VS Code, i get this error

`'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

In my System Properties

I clicked on `environment variables`
I added Path `C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.7\php.exe` in `User variables for User` and `System Variables`

but it still doesn't seem to work. I did find alot of solutions for XAMPP, and tried them but still no luck. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You may need to restart your CMD for the changes to take effect.
- You may need to run a CMD as an administrator.
- You may need to restart your computer for the changes to take effect.